# Andriod sdk missing or corrupted

Tags: java, android, kotlin, sdk

I have been using android since 8 months. But with the newer update, Android Studio started behaving wrongly i.e when it does not auto-suggest me the options in my XML file.

Like before if I typed `"id"` it uses to show me `android:id=""` but not now. So I have the first uninstalled android studio. then I deleted the Android SDK folder present inside the AppData folder.

Now I have downloaded the latest version of the android studio but while installing it, it doesn't let me select all the options in the Android SDK. So, guys, could you help me how could I install it.

[Android SDK missing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JuwwF.png)

Answer (score 0):

In your Android Studio go to Preferences -> Appearance & Behavior -> System Settings -> Android SDK, check if the path in Android SDK Location set or not.

If it is not set then go ahead and set the path to your Android SDK. Android SDK is usually located in your Library -> Android -> sdk

Comment: where is this library folder located?

Comment: Your Home Folder/Library/Android/sdk

Comment: actually it's like that in mac but in windows it used to be in appdata - local - android sdk but i unknowingly deleted that folder . So that's the issue

Comment: Yeah, right. So you just have to make sure that the sdk is present.

Comment: the problem is that i can't select all those options which i have sent in that photo